# Spring POST error whit third entity relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm new on Spring, i would like to store relationship between Exam and Question whith this structure:

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Exam extends UriEntity<Integer> {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @NotBlank
  @Length(min = 1, max = 256)
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="exam")
  private List<ExamQuestion> exams_questions;

@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Question extends UriEntity<Integer> {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @NotBlank
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String statement;

  @NotBlank
  private String answer;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="question")
  private List<ExamQuestion> exams_questions;

@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class ExamQuestion extends UriEntity<Integer> {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
  private Question question;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "exam_id")
  private Exam exam;
```

When i want to store a new ExamQuestion object with POSTMAN

```
{
  "exam": "http://localhost:8080/exams/28",
  "question": "http://localhost:8080/questions/17"
}
```

I get an error 409, and the message:

> NULL not allowed for column \"ID\";

Any could help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen because of the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.

Make sure that in your database schema ID column is set to be auto incremented, since `GenerationType.IDENTITY` uses databases identity column to generate values. Thus if your column is not set to be auto incremented you get this error.

Comment: Solved, perfect, thank you very much, I thought IDENTITY was more restrictive than AUTO and included automatic increment